# Facebook fbsr and session wont delete

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I have a logout.php page. This gets called by clicking logout that has this javascript attached to it:

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          window.location = 'logout.php';
        });
      }
   }
 });
```

On the logout page i have this php code running:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id])) {
    setcookie('fbsr_' . $app_id, $_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], time() - 3600, "/");
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time() - 3600, "/");

    unset($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id]);  
    unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
}
```

The problem is that the javascript does log someone out. The php script will not remove the fbsr and the phpsessid cookies. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Also I tried: $facebook->destroySession(); and it still wont logout.

Comment: Instead of `unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);` use `session_destroy();`. This will ensure the session is cleaned up.

Comment: Do you mean you're not logged out of Facebook, or you're not logged out of your site? `FB.logout` should handle logging out of Facebook, so you shouldn't need to touch the `fb_sr*` cookie.

Comment: It was working that way up untill 2 days ago michael, however now it keeps the stored values from fbsr and PHPSESSID which i cannot for some reason unset. Tried using session_destroy however nothing occured. fbsr_ is still active.

Comment: Melissa, I think you're right... For me too it worked till 3 days ago, and then it broke... Actually, I think php removes cookies, but afterwards fbsr_ cookie is written again (by facebook, I suppose)...

Comment: I believe I ran into the same problem this week ("fbsr" cookie would return after deleting, even when logged out of FB). I opened a ticket with Facebook and they closed it today as "wontfix" because they advise against using the cookie for authentication :(

Comment: link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232377793506796

Answer (score 5):

For some of the applications, FB sets the fbsr cookie under ".your-domain.tld" domain (notice the preceding point). The cookie won't be deleted unless you specify the correct domain. Try this and you'll have logout working:

`setcookie('fbsr_' . $appID, '', time()-3600, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);`

It's a FB bug that makes the cookie not be deleted at logout, so your $fb->getUser() API call returns the former user ID instead of NULL or 0. This is FB world ;)
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even though all cookie pars were right (doublechecked)
What seems to work for me, is 
 setcookie($cookie_name, '', null, '/', '.'.$base_domain);
note the null value instead of: time()-3600

I honestly dont know why that works and the time()-3600 does not, but I cross checked and it works... HTH